# SQL "NOT IN" function not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause, sql-in

Hi can anyone figure out what's wrong with this sql query.
The Not In function is not working properly. in my table the id 1 and 2 should not fetched as they come in subquery in the not in function.

```
select pr.id
     ,pc.title as category
     ,pc.points_required
     ,pc.total_leads_allowed
     ,pr.leadsSold
     ,pr.created 
  from ad_pro_requests pr 
  join ad_pro_categories pc 
   on pc.id = pr.cat_id 
 where pr.cat_id IN(1,2)
    AND pr.id NOT IN(
        select request_id 
        from ad_purchased_leads 
        where user_id = 8
    ) 
   And pr.leadsSold < pc.total_leads_allowed 
   And pc.active =1 
   And pr.status = 1 
   And pr.placeId = 'CA' 
    OR pr.placeId = 6077243 
ORDER by id desc 
limit 0,15
```

Comment: It's almost certainly the `OR` that is messing things up. Wrap that group in parentheses.

Comment: Also, see how much easier it is to follow the code when you format it properly? Please don't make us do that for you in the future.

Comment: that worked for me thanks

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks, I am new to this.I didn't knew

Comment: Your `WHERE` translate to `where (pr.cat_id IN(1,2)
    AND pr.id NOT IN(
        select request_id 
        from ad_purchased_leads 
        where user_id = 8
    ) 
   And pr.leadsSold < pc.total_leads_allowed 
   And pc.active =1 
   And pr.status = 1 
   And pr.placeId = 'CA' )
    OR )pr.placeId = 6077243)`.  Is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You - most likely - need to surround the `OR` condition with parentheses:

```
where 
    pr.cat_id in (1, 2)
    and pr.id not in (...)
    and ...
    and (pr.placeid = 'CA' or pr.placeid = '6077243')
```

Or better yet, use `in`:

```
where 
    pr.cat_id in (1, 2)
    and pr.id not in (...)
    and ...
    and pr.placeid in ('CA', '6077243')
```

Note that I surrounded the literal number with single quotes, since `placeid` seems to be a string.

I would also suggest rewriting the `in` condition as `not exists`. It is usually more efficient, and `null`-safe:

```
where 
    pr.cat_id in (1, 2)
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from ad_purchased_leads apl
        where apl.user_id = 8 and apl.request_id = pr.id
    )
    and pr.leadsSold < pc.total_leads_allowed 
    and pc.active =1 
    and pr.status = 1
    and pr.placeid in ('CA', '6077243')
```

For performance, you want an index on `ad_purchased_leads(user_id, request_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` has lower precedence than `AND`.  Your `WHERE` translate to

```
where (
    pr.cat_id IN(1,2)
        AND pr.id NOT IN(
            select request_id 
            from ad_purchased_leads 
            where user_id = 8
        ) 
       And pr.leadsSold < pc.total_leads_allowed 
       And pc.active =1 
       And pr.status = 1 
       And pr.placeId = 'CA'
) OR (pr.placeId = 6077243)
```

You probably want

```
where pr.cat_id IN(1,2)
    AND pr.id NOT IN(
        select request_id 
        from ad_purchased_leads 
        where user_id = 8
    ) 
   And pr.leadsSold < pc.total_leads_allowed 
   And pc.active =1 
   And pr.status = 1 
   And (pr.placeId = 'CA' OR pr.placeId = 6077243)
```